# Bidirectional behavior in relationships to different models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have some classess with different properties (Requests) which all should have relation to another class (Notification)

My structure is like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

class RequestMixin(object):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text(250))

    @declared_attr
        def __tablename__(self):
        return self.__name__.lower()

    @declared_attr
    def notification_id(self):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('notification.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def notification(self):
        return db.relationship('Notification')

def DailyLeaveRequest(db.Model, RequestMixin):
    demand_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)

def HourlyLeaveRequest(db.Model, RequestMixin):
    demand_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    time_from = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    time_to = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)

def FundRequest(db.Model, RequestMixin):
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)


class Notification(db.Model):
    __tablename__='notification'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    seen = db.Column(db.BOOLEAN, nullable=False, default=False)
    concept = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    # and some relationships to users which doesn't matter here
```

In this way I can access Notification object through each Request object, But since there's no 'backref', I cant access the reverse way.

So what I'm doing now is to check Notification.concept and query on related Request manually. this way:

```
if notification_obj.concept == 1:
    related_request = DailyLeaveRequest.query.filter_by(notification_id=notification_obj.id).first()
elif notification_obj == 2:
    .
    .
```

which is disgusting. (I have lot more than 3 Request classes)

And when I try to add a backref like this:

```
.
.
@declared_attr
def notification(self):
    return db.relationship('Notification', backref='request')
.
.
```

, I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'request' on relationship 'HourlyLeaveRequest.notification': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Notification|notification'

Is there a way to have a class which is related to other different classes WITH reverse access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [SQLAlchemy's polymorphic relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html).

The simplest way to use it with is [joined table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance). It allows you to define a base table with all common attributes, including the relationship to `Notification`.

```
class Request(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text(250))

    notification_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('notification.id'))
    notification = db.relationship('Notification')

    type = db.Column(db.String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'request',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }


class DailyLeaveRequest(Request):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'), primary_key=True)

    demand_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'dailyleave',
    }


class HourlyLeaveRequest(Request):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'), primary_key=True)

    demand_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    time_from = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    time_to = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'hourlyleave',
    }


def FundRequest(Request):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'), primary_key=True)

    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'hourlyleave',
    }
```

You can then query for all `Requests`:

```
requests = Request.query.all()
for request in requests:
    demand_date = getattr(
        request, 'demand_date', 'demand_date not available on this type')
    print(request.type, demand_date)
```

All of the attributes of the `Request` as well as the specific table will be available, but not those of other tables.

You can also query for specific types:

```
requests = DailyLeaveRequest.query.all():
for request in requests:
    print(request.type, request.demand_date)
```

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. I didn't know about polymorphic relationships at all :)